# Parsing error: Caching was left unconfigured. Babel's plugins, presets, and .babelrc.js files can be configured for various types of caching

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, font-awesome

Hi I am trying to use fontawesome with my react front end however I am getting this error
Parsing error: Caching was left unconfigured. Babel's plugins, presets, and .babelrc.js files can be configured
for various types of caching, using the first param of their handler functions

I added the recommended functions such as api.cache(true) but the error didn't go away

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  return {
    plugins: ['macros'],
  }
}
```

babel-plugin-macros.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    'fontawesome-svg-core': {
      'license': 'free'
    }
  }
```

Comment: I faced the same problem and adding the `api.cache(true)` line didn't work for me, so I cleaned the babel cache `rm -rf node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
` and the issue is gone